# Excluding a directory from wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have WordPress installed in a directory in the root and I used htaccess to point the domain name to it directly. I also have a CodeIgniter application in a directory in the root. There are two htaccess files one in the root folder (public_html) the other in the WordPress directory.

I cannot seem to make the CodeIgniter accessible. Please help.

### htaccess in the root folder:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### htaccess in wordpress directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rainoilcom/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule . /rainoilcom/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### htaccess in codeigniter directory

```
SetEnv TZ Africa/Lagos

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /recruitment/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images|uploads|media|swf\.swf)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please include the contents of your .htaccess file in your question.

Comment: What exactly can I do?

Comment: Why do you have WordPress .htaccess directives in your root .htaccess file? "I used htaccess to point the domain name to it directly" - there does not seem to be any directives in the root .htaccess file that does this?

Comment: I dont quite get the question?

Comment: You have WP installed in a subdirectory. In that subdirectory's .htaccess file you have a set of WP directives for that WP installation, but you also have a set of WP directives in the root .htaccess file - why is that?

Comment: "I have wordpress installed in a directory in the root and I used htaccess to point the domain name to it directly." - how did you "point the domain name to it directly"? There does not appear to be anything in the code you have posted above that does this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the offending piece of code. "*SetEnv TZ Africa/Lagos*". Deleted it and I'm good.